# popup alert when http request last x seconds with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to popup and alert saying "Error Contacting Server" when http request doesn't get any feedback.

```
.controller('items_ctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.shop_id=localStorage.getItem("shop_id");
        $http.get('http://localhost/myapp/spree/stocks.php').success(function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            $scope.item=data;

           });
    }])
```

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507678/in-angular-http-service-how-can-i-catch-the-status-of-error hope this helps!!

Comment: On a side note:
"The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead. If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to `false` then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error." Taken from: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `then` instead of `success/error` methods

Here is your updated code

```
.controller('items_ctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.shop_id=localStorage.getItem("shop_id");
        $http.get('http://localhost/myapp/spree/stocks.php').then(function(data){
               console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
               $scope.item=data;

           }, function(error){
               alert("Error contacting server");
           });
        }])
```

Comment: the alert should pop up after for example 20 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You should specify error callback function.

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

For more information please see 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

Use promise for it .Set some timeout in your javascript.

```
var cancelReq= $q.defer();
$http.get('/someUrl', {timeout: cancelReq.promise}).success(successCallback);
$timeout(showErrorPopup, 3000);
```

after timeout , resolve it and then show popup

```
function showErrorPopup(){
   cancelReq.resolve(); 
//popup code
}
```